# how to find decimal dot

Tags: java, double, decimal

I have problem searching the position of decimal dot in my char array.

I transformed double (Price) into char array using:

```
char[] arrayPrice=Double.toString(Ad[i].Price()).toCharArray();
```

Now I want to find the position of decimal dot.

I tried

```
for (int k=0; k<arrayPrice.length; k++) {
    if (".".equals(arrayPrice[k])) {
        dotPosition=k;
    }
}
```

but it gives me 0 all the time.

Thanks!

Comment: That's because you are using `equals()` with a `String` passing in a `char`. That will always, regardless of the `String` or the `char` result in `false`.

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates this.

Comment: String provides some util methods for that, you can use `String#indexOf(..)`, but for that you have to use a String rather than `char[]`

Comment: For primitive type `char` just use `==` to compare: `arrayPrice[k] == '.'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you are comparing different types, this will always be `false`.

```
".".equals(arrayPrice[k])
```

Instead  you can use

```
'.' == arrayPrice[k]
```

But String class provide some utils method for doing that, for example [String#indexOf(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29)

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified character

```
String price=Double.toString(Ad[i].Price());
price.indexOf('.');
```

Answer (score 1):

A "." acts as a wildcard.
so instead of using

```
  ".".equals(arrayPrice[k])
```

you may use

```
  '.'==arrayPrice[k]
```

in the if statement.
This will surely fix the problem.